# simple vector question

Tags: calculus

In a book I'm reading it mentions

'For motion along a straight line, i.e. in a 1-dimensional space, the velocities are also contained in that 1-D space since they are just numbers. For general motion along a curve or 2-d or 3-d space we need a multidimensional object to represent it which should also have a magnitude and direction. A geometric figure with these properties is an arrow - the moivation for how we define a vector.'

http://www.mecmath.net/calc3book.pdf

p.3 paragraph 2

I don't uderstand. An arrow isn't a multi-dimensional object.. or is this part of the book trying to state that the arrow is multidimensional because it can cut through different dimensions? Oh I think I may understand now - it basically is saying that motion on a straight line is contained in that same dimension but motion along a curve changes rate and motion that can have a positive or negative magnitude - these two cant be contained in a single dimension so we need an object that can cut through different dimensions.  Is this an ok way of thinking about it?

clear answers only please this really isn't a relevant part of the book and at the moment I'm just being introduced to multivariable calc I'm sure it'll become more clear as I do problems and read further on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the author has accidentally phrased things in a way that are unclear. If a point is constrained to move only a long a line then you need just one number to describe its position, and you also need just one number to describe its speed along that line. But the same is true of a point constrained to follow a curve in 2 or 3 dimensions.

I think the author means to contrast a point constrained to moving along a line with a point not constrained to a line or a curve, even though it does in fact trace out a curve. If you don't know in advance which curve a point is going to follow in a 3D space, you're going to need three numbers to say where it is at any moment in time. If you do know it's on a particular curve, then you typically only need one number. To work in generality it's useful to assume nothing about your points in advance so for the rest of the book you'll probably need 3 coordinates (in a 3d space).

Comment: ty ``````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

Not generally a good idea to think about "positive or negative magnitude." Vector magnitude is always positive. But basically yes, you're thinking about it right. To talk about the motion of an object on a curve that "cuts through different dimensions," you need to be able to talk about its speed and direction or (equivalently) its motion on the x-dimension, and in the y-dimension, and in the z-dimension, and for that you need more than just a single number.